# connect to a access database in java using udl file

Tags: java, database, ms-access

How can I connect to an access database in java using an udl file ?

I 've looked around and found some threads for c# and also some threads for mysql database but never exactly what I'm asking and how to do this.

I also tried connecting without udl and had some trouble with 64 bit systems and 32 bit systems. I don't have problems with udl and c# when I'm connecting to 64 bit and 32 bit.
So I'm also trying to get around this problem by using this method in java.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what a .udl file is, but Java connects to databases using JDBC, preferably with a type IV, 100% driver.

You're out of luck with Access.  The JDBC-ODBC bridge driver is only available in 32 bit JVMs.  It was never intended to be more than a stop gap, so it's not part of the 64 bit JVMs that I've seen.  You'll have to purchase a licensed Access driver.

Comment: you can use the 32 bits jvm in 64 bits systems

Comment: If you're using a 64 bit JVM, the bridge driver isn't included.